# Problem creating root BusinessProcessType in PowerShell with Tridion Core service

Tags: core-service, web8.5, topology-manager

I want to create a root Business Process Type using Tridion Core Service Session Aware Client (8.5). But I have a problem creating a Business process type.

```
using namespace Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client
Using namespace System.Uri
Import-Module Tridion-CoreService

$user = "domain\user"
if(-not $credential){
    $credential = Get-Credential -UserName $user -Message "Remote Server Tridion Administrator Account"
}


$tcsconnection = @{
        hostname       = "cms.poc2.domain.internal"
        version        = "Web-8.5"   # 2011-SP1, 2013, 2013-SP1, Web-8.1, Web-8.5
        ConnectionType = "default"    # Default, SSL, LDAP, LDAP-SSL, netTcp, Basic, Basic-SSL
        CredentialType = "Windows"
}
Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings @tcsconnection 

$settings = Get-TridionCoreServiceSettings

try
{
    $client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
    $client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = $credential
    $client.GetApiVersion()
}

catch 
{
    Write-Output "Failed to connect TridionCoreService on $($tcsconnection.hostname)"
}

$businessProcessType = New-Object BusinessProcessTypeData
$businessProcessType.Title = "DooHickey"
```

> 8.5.0
>
> The property 'Title' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. At line:35 char:1
>   + $businessProcessType.Title = "DooHickey"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: Weird. What do you get if you do `Get-Member $businessProcessType` ?

Comment: BTW, your error handling is a bit dubious: if connection fails, you write an (informative) message to the output and try to continue... :-)

Comment: This is just an test example not real code

Answer (score 1):

Logged in on new session and problem was gone. No ideas why it would not work yesterday. Thanks to Rick for Get-Member suggestion.

Comment: Just a note that when creating new items, I suggest to always call $client.GetDefaultData instead of creating the data object yourself. That will initialize a lot of the properties for you.